# Create coupon for special product

Tags: coupon

I create a coupon for a special product and i do these steps:

1. Log-in to admin
2. Promotions -> Shopping Cart Price Rules
3. Click Add New Rule
4. I fill Rule Information, and i set coupon100 for coupon code.
5. click Conditions tab
6. Click + button icon
7. Select Product attribute combination
8. Click + button icon
9. Select SKU
10. I see SKU is ...
11. I Put my product SKU over there
12. In action tab i set discount price.
13. Save rule.

Then when i buy that product when i enter the coupon code i get an error that **the coupon code is not valid**.

Where is the problem?

**EDIT:**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of how the conditions and actions sections look like?

Comment: @Marius : Yes, i can, but my magento language is Persian. do you have problem with this or i upload the screenshot?

Comment: My Persian is kind of rusty :). but you can change the admin language for the current session from the bottom dropdown with all the languages. take the screenshot and then you can change the language back.

Comment: @Marius: you can see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you problem is this :

All of these conditions are true:

- sku contains 01
- sku contains 02

I'm not 100% sure how the `contains` directive works, but I think it the sku `01234` is not matched by the `contains 01` restriction.
I think the system checks something like `sku is 01 and sku is 02` that will always be `false`.
Try removing one of the restrictions or chance the top condition to `one of these conditions are true`.

Comment: yes, i change product and it's work. that product that i set sku is a group product, it means that i can't use coupon for a group product?

Comment: So, you basically need a rule saying that if products with sku 01 and sku 02 are in the cart you can apply the coupon, right?

Comment: actually when i set sku 01, i mean that per product in this group can have this coupon, is it possible? or i should add per product in conditions?

Comment: I think you need to set the discounts per simple product